# Creating a playlist with dynamic number of songs in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a playlist feature on my website. The backend is already worked out, now I just need to be able to display it on the front end.

I am new to angular and I understand how I can display a dynamic number of playlists, but how can I have a dynamic number of songs for each playlist (based on the number of songs each playlist has, as dictated in the database).

Can I accomplish this with nested components? I would really appreciate a design structure/term or a link to a tutorial on how I can accomplish this feature.

Basically what I want is:

Playlists on a web page, and once I click on a playlist, it displays the correct number of songs in it. (I know how to get information from my backend, just not how to display it on angular)

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest starting at the [basic tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) that will walk you through almost exactly this scenario. Come on back if you get stuck in the effort. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngFor to display songs:

```
<div>
    <p *ngFor="let song of songs">
        {{ song.name }} <!-- here you can use anything to display one song. -->
    </p>
</div>
```

***songs*** is the array of songs(your playlist) that you fetched from your backend.